# ADAL iOS Authentication to Azure Web API

Tags: ios, api, azure, oauth, adal

Right now, I have a native azure app that my iOS app uses ADAL to authenticate to with no issues. I've added a Web API in azure and it's being managed by the Azure API Management resource. I have this API using an oAuth server that uses Azure AD for authentication (all created within the Azure API Management).

The issue I'm having is the oAuth token I'm receiving from my iOS App is not being accepted by my Web API. They are both using oAuth to the same Azure Active Directory. I tried changing in my iOS app, to use the Web API app client ID instead of the native app client ID. The issue then becomes during authentication, it needs a "client_secret" in the request. Looking at the ADAL iOS library, I'm not seeing a method to get a token that passes in a client secret as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down to the Keys section, you will see the key as the client secret. They are used for calling the web api.
[image]

These two methods of authenticating the applications are referred to as interactive (user signs in) and non-interactive (app provides its own credentials). In the non-interactive mode, you must assign the service principal to a role with the correct permission. About the AAD authentication's more information, you could refer to: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal/

Comment: do you know how to add the secret to ADAuthenticationContext ?